# Parse "method not allowed when pinning is enabled" after migrating to new server

Tags: methods, parse-platform, migration, parse-server, pinning

I've inherited a Parse app that works fine on Parse.com, but after migrating to a new server, I'm seeing this error. As far as I can tell, this app *doesn't* enable pinning (Parse.enableLocalDatastore() is not called anywhere)

Q: Is there anything about the server setup that could be an issue here?

Comment: Hi , can you please show how you initialize parse SDK on the client side?

Comment: BAM! Your request made me discover what is wrong. I received instructions to use the following code, but the <localDataStoreEnabled> is wrong.

Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {

        configuration.applicationId = kParseAppId;

        configuration.clientKey = kParseClientKey;

        configuration.server = kParseURL;

        configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = YES;
    }]];

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted you to notice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I incorrectly initialized Parse with config item

configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = YES